# How to fix "zlib.js:51 Z_MIN_MEMLEVEL error"?

Tags: angular7, node-modules

On ng serve, i receive error' zlib.js:51 Z_MIN_MEMLEVEL, 2¿¥  0¿¥%¬ ^', yesterday everything was working fine, is something changed in npm ? please see error image attached
 [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCmkY.png)

Comment: can you recreate this on stackblitz?

Comment: I just has started working again, i even did not reload laptop.